# how we can select checkbox using the keyboard

Tags: html

I have multiple inputs on a page how we can select checkbox using keyboard without the use of javascript,

Here is my code:

```
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="text">
```

By using tab key we travel one input to other how we can checkbox using keybord.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like you said use the Tab key to navigate and then press + or - . If this doesnt work try with the space key.